# Write-Eventlog pipe issue

Tags: powershell, event-log

Task:
Writing piped data from object to eventlog:

```
RecId|Date/Time|Sev|Src|EvtType|Sensor|EvtDetail
0001|01/01/1600:00:00|INF|BMC|Eventlog|SELFullness|LogCleared
0002|01/01/1600:00:01|MAJ|BMC|Eventlog|Progress|PostError
0003|01/01/1600:00:02|INF|BMC|PowerUnit|HostPower|PowerOff
0004|01/01/1600:00:03|MAJ|BMC|SystemFirmware|SELFullness|PostError
0005|01/01/1600:00:04|INF|BMC|OsBoot||C:bootcompleted
```

This little CSV is stored in D:\Powershell\Bmc.log is nearly a parsed output of `ipmitool.exe` (`isel -c`) on a server.

```
$raw = Get-Content .\Bmc.log
$sel = ConvertFrom-CSV -InputObject $raw -Delimiter "|"
$sel | Where-Object {$_.Sev -eq "INF"} | Out-GridView
```

This works well, I can use `$sel` as object, can list its members etc.
Now I want to dump all records to eventlog, but it does not work.
My Approach:

```
New-Eventlog -LogName HardwareEvents -Source BMC
$sel | Where-Object {$_.Sev -eq "INF"} | Write-Eventlog -LogName HardwareEvents -Source BMC -EventId 999 -Message {$_.EvtDetail} -EntryType INFORMATION
```

It seems that `Write-Eventlog` does not accept pipes.
Aim is not to use a loop.

Comment: "Aim is not to use a loop" - why?

Comment: You are correct about `Write-EventLog` in that it does not accept pipeline input. Therefore a foreach loop would be a simple way to address that.

Comment: Yeah, if you don't use a loop, `New-EventLog` certainly would have to.  You also might see a bit better performance using `$sel = Import-Csv -Path .\Bmc.log -Delimiter "|"` instead of Get-Content and ConvertFrom-Csv.

Comment: Mathias - I like short code Matt - Yes, but I like short code Bacon - I know, but later I will pipe the command directly to $raw.

Answer (score 1):

As you suspected and others have pointed out, `Write-EventLog` doesn't read from the pipeline. Wrap it in a `ForEach-Object` statement:

```
$sel | Where-Object {$_.Sev -eq "INF"} | ForEach-Object {
  Write-EventLog -LogName HardwareEvents -Source BMC -EventId 999 -Message $_.EvtDetail -EntryType INFORMATION
}
```

Otherwise you'd need to wrap `Write-EventLog` in a custom function that does process pipeline input:

```
function Write-EventLogMessage {
  [CmdletBinding()]
  Param(
    [Parameter(
      Mandatory=$true,
      Position=0
      ValueFromPipeline=$true,
      ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true
    )]
    [string]$Message
  )

  Process {
    Write-EventLog -LogName HardwareEvents -Source BMC -EventId 999 -Message $Message -EntryType INFORMATION
  }
}

$sel | Where-Object {$_.Sev -eq "INF"} | Write-EventLogMessage
```

Comment: Ansgar, your code is short enough for me, great. Does anybody have interests on seeing the whole code for reading out Server BMCs using IPMI?